# Crear metodo show() en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de control de bibliotecas, a la hora de realizar una vista individual de un elemento de la base de datos empleo el método `show` de mi `LibroController` de la siguiente forma:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $libros = Libro::find($id);
    return view('libro.show', ['libro'=>$this->libro]);
}
```

y una vista `show.blade.php` asi:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content') 

@include('alerts.request')

  {!!Form::model($libro,['route'=>  ['libro.show',$libro->id],'method'=>'POST','files'=> true])!!}

 <p class="info">AUTOR:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->autor}}</p>
 <p class="info">IDIOMA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->idioma}}</p>
 <p class="info">PAGINAS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->paginas}}</p>


{!!Form::close()!!}


@stop
```

Según tengo entendido emplear el `{!!Form::model!!}` me ahorraría el crear la ruta, aún asi me sale el siguiente error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son mis rutas

```
Route::get('/','FrontController@index');
Route::get('contacto','FrontController@contacto');
Route::get('reviews','FrontController@reviews');
Route::get('admin','FrontController@admin');
Route::get('ver','FrontController@ver');

Route::get('password/email','Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email','Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}','Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset','Auth\PasswordController@postReset');

Route::resource('mail','MailController');

Route::resource('usuario','UsuarioController');
Route::resource('persona','PersonaController');
Route::resource('libro','LibroController');
```

Se agradece cualquier aporte.

Comment: Ya tienes definida tu ruta en **routes.php**?

Comment: segun tengo entendido el  {!!Form::model($libro,['route'=>  ['libro.show',$libro->id],'method'=>'POST','files'=> true])!!}ahorraria la creacion de la ruta para el show, porque en el caso del edit y create si me funciono aun asi ahi estan las rutas

Comment: A tu metodo show le estas pasando un parametro y tu ruta *LibroController" no esta recibiendo nada... 
Deberías cambiarlo a Route::get('libro/{id}','LibroController@show');

SEGÚN LA DOCUMENTACIÓN DEL LARAVEL 5.4

Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'user' => 'admin_user'
]]);

esa dirección será igual a /user/{admin_user}

fuente: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers

Answer (score 3):

El problema es debido a que le estás pasando el valor equivocado al view en tu controller. Por lo que $this->libros no existe y te dará el error que reportas.

Así que tu código debe funcionar si lo haces de esta forma.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $libros = Libro::find($id);
    return view('libro.show', ['libro'=>$libros]);
}
```